# How to set Excel Border as Outside for all cell programatically using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I wish to set border for all cell as outside border. I export data form grid to excel. if one cell border.left == null, then excel was not shown left border line in excel.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1:A20", Type.Missing);
range.BorderAround(Type.Missing, Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThick, Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Type.Missing);
```